# Share/access list Content across all Site Collections in Office365

Tags: list, office-365, site-collection

We are using Sharepoint 2013 in Office 365 for our Intranet.

We have 5 different sub-companys each having their own site collection.
In those site collections they all have their lists/libraries.

For example Site Collection A & B each have a list of locations they do business at.

Now IT (which is in Site Collection C) wants to make a List with all the Equipment they have to service at all the locations of A & B.

Can I pull the location data form the list in A & B to a list in C? I know this is possible inside a single site collection.

For another Site Collection we would like to to combine two lists, each on a different site collection but same structure into one.

The only thing that seems to be "shareable" across all site collections seem to be the term store, but that doesn't really help.

I searched a bit for myself and the way I understood it is that something like that is only possible with on premise, but I am not really sure because all we did with SharePoint so far is only using basic libraries/lists and slapping a design on top of it, nothing fancy.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a custom webpart and insert it into a page. The custom webpart would be able to pull data from a different site collection. I don't think there is any way to do it OOTB.

See this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ramg/archive/2009/04/22/implementing-a-simple-cross-site-collection-list-view-webpart.aspx

Comment: The code in that link is Server Object Model code that need to run in a server side solution. This is not supported in Office 365.

Comment: Ohh whoops, let me see what else I can find